# Encrypted ubuntu 22.04 with Grub minimal bash like line

Tags: grub2, encryption

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 in an encrypted way following the official guide ([Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019)). At the firs boot the system ask me the password and, after the typing of the password, a Grub minimal bash appears. I tried on my laptop (along side another partition with Ubuntu) and on an old laptop (without any other partition) but the resultat is the same. What could I do? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Following the instructions, during a grafical method, I can't install it along side an other distribution.

Comment: I looked through the How To. The list of commands is quite long. It is hard to troubleshoot without knowing what you may have done wrong at which point. Trying this alongside another distribution makes it more difficult. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1442790/edit) and add information about the partition structure of the "other distribution" before the install, and the partition structure after the encrypted installation. It will also help if you are installing alongside Windows, or another distribution of Linux.